# tkinter list of widget properties

Tags: tkinter, properties, documentation

I'm new to Tkinter (and Python) and I'm trying to find just a basic list of widgets with their properties and values. See the list below where I have been reading. So far the doc I have found is all of the style "widget x, y and z all support property z."

That's not what I'm looking for. I don't care what properties widgets share or have in common or where they might have been inherited from. All I care about is if "I decide to use widget Checkbutton", what are all the properties that that widget supports. And what do I have to include to get them.

I know such a list or document will contain many repeated entries. But such a "cookbook" is really handy when you're just learning a language.

And I'd really prefer not to create such a "cookbook" by myself. But I will if I have to.

Here is where I have been:

Tkinter standard widget attributes
https://zetcode.com/tkinter/attributes/

tkinter.ttk — Tk themed widgets
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html

15.27. Common Widget Properties
https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/09_modifying_widgets.html

Thanks.

Comment: i don't know what You mean but I pretty much always use this source for tkinter: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Comment: These were what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical tk documentation (tkinter is just a wrapper around tcl/tk) is the [tk man pages](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/contents.htm). They document all of the widgets and all of the options.

If you're curious about a specific widget you can use the python `dir` or `help` functions on a widget or widget class.

Comment: These were what I was looking for. Thanks.